# DI error when calling an assembly from an injected assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, ninject

so i'm having a few problems with dependency injection.. i get the following error:

> Error activating IDocumentReadRepository No matching bindings are
>   available, and the type is not self-bindable. Activation path:   3)
>   Injection of dependency IDocumentReadRepository into parameter
>   readRepository of constructor of type ReadOrchestrator   2) Injection
>   of dependency IReadOrchestrator into parameter

so i'm injecting my readOrchestrator into my MVC3 app which is fine.. but the problem arises when in my readOrchestrator i call a method in my IDocumentReadRepository.

my ReadOrchestrator looks like:

```
public class ReadOrchestrator : IReadOrchestrator
{
    private readonly IDocumentReadRepository _readRepository;

    public ReadOrchestrator(IDocumentReadRepository readRepository)
    {
        _readRepository = readRepository;
    }

    public UserFeed GetUserFeed(string userName, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var feed = _readRepository.Query<UserFeed>(x => x.UserName == (string)userName
            .Page(pageNumber, pageSize));
        return feed;
    }
}

    public class DocumentReadRepository : IDocumentReadRepository
    {
        readonly IDocumentStore _documentStore;

        public DocumentReadRepository(IDocumentStore documentStore)
        {
            _documentStore = documentStore;
        }
...
}
```

Should i be using DI in this situation? if so, how/where should i do the binding for the IDocumentReadRepository? or should i just be creating a new instance of it each time i call my ReadOrchestrator?

thanks

Comment: How do inject the `ReadOrchestrator`? Do the same for `DocumentReadRepository` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for sure you need to register or bind `IDocumentReadRepository` to a concrete implementation namely `DocumentReadRepository`.

You have a BindModule somewhere in your codebase.

Do the binding for `DocumentReadRepository` and ninject will wire the dependencies for you when an instance of `ReadOrchestrator`wants to be created.

Like this

```
this.Bind<IDocumentReadRepository>.To<DocumentReadRepository>();
```

Comment: i tried binding my kernal to it at MVC level.. but doesnt work

Comment: Clean the project from any `Ninject` code then Add the `Ninject` and `Ninject.Web.Mvc` through NuGet and it will configure it for you.

Comment: that was the problem, i didnt have ninject referenced properly!